# Problem getting the expected out from CI_Controller function to Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I don't know what's wrong with my code. I cannot get the expected output from my CI_Controller when I call out the function. I suspect that my CI_Controller is not returning any value to my Ajax function.

**Here is my CI_Controller function**

```
public function check_student_id($data){
   $result = $this->page_model->check_id($data);
   return $result;
}
```

**And then the CI_Model function**

```
public function check_id($data){
   $this->db->where('student_id', $data);
   $result = $this->db->count_all_results('users');
   if($result > 0){
     return true;
   }
   else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

**And finally, the Ajax function**

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#base_url')+"pages/check_student_id/"+student_id,
    method: "POST",
    data: {'student_id':student_id},
    success: function(data){
      if(data == true){
        $('#student_id_error_message').show();
        $('student_id_error_message').text('Student ID has been already registered.');
        $('#student_id_error_message').addClass('text-danger font-italic my-0');
      }
      else{
        $('#registerForm').hide(600);
        $('#registerSuccess').text('You have successfully registered!');
        $('#registerSuccess').addClass('text-success py-3');
        $('#registerSuccess').show(600);
      }
    }
  })
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: I've tried this  code -> console.log(data+'No data passed.'); in the else statement. 
Output: No data passed.

The data passed from the CI_Controller must be false because the student id is already in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of return, You should echo $result in controller's function.

```
public function check_student_id($data){
   $result = $this->page_model->check_id($data);
   echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Sir. The output now in console.log(data) is now 1. The echo $result works. Thank you very much for the help.